# How may I solve 'Cannot assign value of type 'CATextLayerAlignmentMode' to type 'String'?

Tags: swift, alignment, scenekit, arkit

```
func createNewBubbleParentNode(_ text: String) -> SCNNode {
    let billBoardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
    billBoardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y
    
    let bubble = SCNText(string: text, extrusionDepth: CGFloat(bubbleDepth))
    var font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 0.15)
    bubble.font = font
    bubble.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    
    return bubbleNodeParent
}
```

How can I solve 'Cannot assign value of type 'CATextLayerAlignmentMode' to type 'String' with this type of function?

Thanks for your answers!!

Loïc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to use a value `CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue`. This value is used not only in iOS but also in macOS.

```
bubble.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue
```

Here's a full code version:

```
import ARKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        
        let textNode = self.createBubbleNode("SceneKit")
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

        sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    }
    
    func createBubbleNode(_ text: String) -> SCNNode {            
        let bubble = SCNText(string: text, extrusionDepth: 0.02)
        bubble.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 0.15)
        bubble.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        bubble.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue
        let bubbleNode = SCNNode(geometry: bubble)
        return bubbleNode
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace `kCAAlignmentCenter` by `CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue`

Comment: That was so useful! Thanks a lot!!